# Standard values in list which can't be deleted but ability to add to list

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

For my application I can add a status to a specific task like "finished, in progress, not started". I want these 3 status objects to be untouchable (the user can't delete or edit them) but the user can have the ability to add other Status objects and delete those.

Any idea how I can achieve a behaviour like this with NHibernate?

Before I was using NHibernate, I've just set a boolean in the database like "fixed" and I checked if this was true or false to determine if i could be deleted or not.

Do I have to use the same approach with a boolean property in the status object?

Or are there any other approaches?

Answer (score 0):

The question is, if you really need these standard values in the database. I suggest keeping only the variable (user-defined) values in the DB and to add the standard values programmatically to your lists and set their "fixed" flag to `true` at the same time. This flag does not need to be in the DB, i.e. it will not be mapped. This way these special values won't be deletable.

Of course, this works only if you don't have referential integrity constraints on that column.

Comment: this won't work just like you said because my "Task" object has a "Status" as a property, so it has to remind which status the task has.

Comment: If the task table does not have a foreign key on the status_id column, then it should work.